# Dual monitors using a gigabyte m68mt s2p motherboard with a d-sub port and a geforce 430 graphics card

Tags: multiple-monitors

Im having trouble setting up dual monitors. Is it possible to run Dual monitors using a gigabyte m68mt s2p motherboard with a d-sub port and a geforce 430 graphics card?